# Visual Studio say package android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'v installed Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package and other dependencies package for it in empty android project.
But i'v received errors that say :

> Unzipping failed. Please download
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r38.zip
>   and extract it to the
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\24.2.1\content
>   directory.

I'v downloaded this package and extract it and copy Support.Compat package in the requested path.
But i received multi errors from different java libraries.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHmP4.png)

Comment: See my document on this topic here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: @JonDouglas Thank you for your answer. I'v used this document and my problem was solved. But i'm not able to build my project, because I got an error that say: resource directory 'path\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B81A750477D10031D1844681B0F7EB17\res.